# Only one mail to one domain

Tags: php, apache, email, smtp, phpmailer

Why if i sent mail from PHP to two person with same domain then message is not sent?
For example if i use PHPMailer (in other class i have the same error):

```
$mail->addAddress('whoto1@example1.com', 'John Doe1');
$mail->addAddress('whoto2@example2.com', 'John Doe2');
$mail->addAddress('whoto3@example3.com', 'John Doe3');
$mail->Send();
```

This working ok - all persons with theses mails receive them. But if i have:

```
$mail->addAddress('whoto1@example1.com', 'John Doe1');
$mail->addAddress('whoto2@example2.com', 'John Doe2');
$mail->addAddress('whoto3@example3.com', 'John Doe3');
$mail->Send();
```

Then any mails is delivered.

if:

```
$mail->addAddress('whoto1@example1.com', 'John Doe1');
$mail->Send();
$mail->addAddress('whoto2@example2.com', 'John Doe2');
$mail->Send();
$mail->addAddress('whoto3@example3.com', 'John Doe3');
$mail->Send();
```

Then working good.

Where i can found a solution? I would like send mails in one portion, same as example 2. Why this not working on my server?

Comment: What is the difference between the first and the second code snippet? They are identical, there is no reason why one should work and the other is not.

Answer (score -1):

you could set up an array of contacts to email, then mail them all. e.g.

```
for(x = 0; x < array.length; x++){
$address[x] ... do whatever with address
$name[x] ... do whatever with name
use a send mail function to email each person individuly
}
```